# STM32F769I display not showing framebuffer content

Tags: stm32, embedded, display, linux, ltdc

I am trying to get video to work on STM32F769I device.

What I have done already is that I have changed the device tree so it has the required support and enabled the kernel features required for it to work, that resulted in `/dev/fb0` framebuffer device.

If I write to framebuffer and save its contents it works perfectly fine, but its contents are not displayed on the screen, the only thing I see on the screen is ST splash screen and it would not change.

If I try to do any of the following the board hangs and I have to reboot it:

- `echo 0 0 > /sys/class/graphics/fb0/pan`
- `cat /sys/class/graphics/fb0/modes > /sys/class/graphics/fb0/mode`

Additional information print:

```
~ # for file in /sys/class/graphics/fb0/*; do echo "$file";  cat "$file"; done
/sys/class/graphics/fb0/bits_per_pixel
16
/sys/class/graphics/fb0/blank
/sys/class/graphics/fb0/console
/sys/class/graphics/fb0/cursor
/sys/class/graphics/fb0/dev
29:0
/sys/class/graphics/fb0/device
cat: read error: Is a directory
/sys/class/graphics/fb0/mode
/sys/class/graphics/fb0/modes
U:480x800p-0
/sys/class/graphics/fb0/name
stmdrmfb
/sys/class/graphics/fb0/pan
0,0
/sys/class/graphics/fb0/power
cat: read error: Is a directory
/sys/class/graphics/fb0/rotate
0
/sys/class/graphics/fb0/state
0
/sys/class/graphics/fb0/stride
1024
/sys/class/graphics/fb0/subsystem
cat: read error: Is a directory
/sys/class/graphics/fb0/uevent
MAJOR=29
MINOR=0
DEVNAME=fb0
/sys/class/graphics/fb0/virtual_size
480,800
```

Please help me get the display to work, I will gladly provide more info if requested.

Answer (score 1):

Try this repo:

https://adrianalin.gitlab.io/popsblog.me/posts/build-linux-for-stm32f769i-disco-using-buildroot/

It works fine on my STM32F769I Discovery board.